# Retrieve text inside #{ }

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
#{king} for a ##{day}, ##{fool} for a #{lifetime}
```

And the following (broken) regex:

```
[^#]#{[a-z]+}
```

I want to match all #{words} but not the ##{words} (Doubling '#' acts like escaping) .

Today I've noticed that the regex I have is ignoring the first word (refuses to match #{king}, but correctly ignores ##{day} and ##{fool}) .

```
>>> regex = re.compile("[^#]#{[a-z]+}")
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u' #{lifetime}']
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the current regex in order to suit my needs ?
I guess the problem is with `[^#]` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a "negative lookbehind assertion", the correct regex would look like this:

```
import re
t = "#{king} for a ##{day}, ##{fool} for a #{lifetime}"
re.findall(r'(?<!#)#{([a-z]+)}', t)
```

returns

```
['king', 'lifetime']
```

**Explanation:**

The `(?<!prefix)pattern`  expression matches `pattern` only if it's not preceeded by `prefix`.

Comment: Your solution is better, I forgot about negative look-behind.

Comment: Cool feature ? Is this python regex specific ?

Comment: @Andrei, no it seems it's not python specific (according to [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)), but they say: "flavors like JavaScript, Ruby and Tcl do not support lookbehind at all, even though they do support lookahead."

Answer (score 2):

Use a look-behind construction:

```
>>> s='#{king} for a ##{day}, ##{fool} for a #{lifetime}'
>>> r=re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<=[^#]))#{\w+}')
>>> r.findall(s)
['#{king}', '#{lifetime}']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(?:^|[^#])#{[a-z]+}")
>>> regex.findall(string)
['#{king}', ' #{lifetime}']
>>>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the problem with this solution (not using the negative lookbehind assertion) is that it wouldn't work for `'#{king}#{blah}'` - `findall` returns non-overlapping matches.

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with `(?:^|[^#])`. Like you inferred, just `[^#]` means one character which is not #, which obviously there isn't at beginning of line.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
re.compile('^#\{[\w]+\}')
```

Comment: Did you try it? It matches only `#{king}` but not also `#{lifetime}`.